# ReadCommitted IsolationLevel

Tags: database, relational-database

Does ReadCommitted Isolation Level set any blocks on selected data? Will it fail in the following workflow:

```
transaction 1: read record with id 1
transaction 2: read record with id 1
transaction 1: update record with id 1 and commit
transaction 2: update record with id 1 and commit
```

According to my knowledge, ReadCommitted should allow it, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is allowed. Unless you externally synchronise the clients such that the second gives the `COMMIT` only after the first one has received positive confirmation that its commit succeeded, the order in which the `UPDATE`s are performed is undefined (the database only needs to pretend that these were serialized, but there is no ordering guarantee), so it helps to write them so that they modify existing data rather than replace it, and/or quote the `SELECT` result in a `WHERE` clause to make the `UPDATE` conditional on the row being unmodified. E.g.:

```
-> SELECT key,value FROM mytable WHERE key = 1;
1 row:
key|value
1  |foo

-> UPDATE mytable SET value='bar' WHERE key = 1 AND value = 'foo';
0 rows affected
```

This shows that another query modified the row in between.

Comment: But normally a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype column, not a data column, would be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The answer probably depends on which DBMS you are using.  In Oracle it will not fail, but transaction 2's update will be blocked by transaction 1's until transaction 1 commits, at which point transaction 2's update will go through.

Comment: Greetings.  That sounds like pure 2PL.  My understanding (from your other post) was that with MVCC, there is no blocking ?

Comment: @PerfDBA.  Hi.  Which other post are you referring to?  There certainly is blocking in Oracle when 2 session attempt to update the same row.  What Oracle's MVCC ensures is that readers never block writers, and writers never block readers.